# jQuery onclick not working properly with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have used onClick method to confirm update for my Bootstrap form. but when i click create button it popup the confirm message without going to validation.

wht i want is if user click create button first it will show the required field validation and after all success only confirm popup should display..

please advice

```
  <form data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"
                                  action="{{ action('Admin\UserController@store') }}">

                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label class="control-label popup-label">Full Name</label>
                                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name"
                                               value="{{ old('full_name') }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label class="control-label popup-label">Username</label>
                                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                                               value="{{ old('username') }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label class="control-label popup-label">Password</label>
                                        <input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters"
                                               type="password" class="form-control"
                                               name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to create this admin?');">Create</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your create button is of submit type, its default action is to submit the form. Make it of type button and use the below function:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createBtn();">Create</button>

<script>
     function createBtn(){
          if(confirm('Do you want to create this admin?')){
                document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
          }
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using the Bootstrap Validator plugin: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

This plugin provides a way to know when the form has been validated by providing you with an event you can listen on.

```
('#form').validator().on('validate.bs.validator', function (e) {
    console.log('validated.');
    // perform confirm and other post-validation tasks...
   confirm('Do you want to create this admin?');
}
```